# How to return specific int values from an array; How to make a testclass?

Tags: java, arrays

I started to code an assignment for uni, but after a short while, i got stuck.

```
public class MostCommonElemnt
{
    //private int[] liste;
    public MostCommonElemnt()
    {
        //int[] liste = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    }
```

Is it bad to initialize an array in the constructor, or is it just not necassary?

```
    public int findMostCommonElemnt(int[] list)
    {
        int help = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < liste.length; i++)
        {
            help = list[i];

        }
        return help; 
    }
```

Here i tried to get a specific int value (or number) returned from my int array, but "help" only returns the last number from the int array. How do i get the 2nd or 4th? To see all of them i can use System.out.println();

```
    public static void main (int[] args)
    {
        //int[] liste = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        System.out.println(new MostCommonElemnt().findMostCommonElemnt(int[] list));
    }
}
```

In this section i tried to make a testMethod but, i can not get it to work,
BlueJ (we have to use it for uni) always complaints about something. 
I especially to not know, what to do after the

```
    new MostCommonElemnt().
```

I just want, the programm to take specific numbers, with which i want to test. e.g: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7...}
otherwise i always have to type them in, which gets boring fast.

Comment: I normally don't say this quickly, but please go read a basic programming book before posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Sossenbinder Yeah, you are right. I already have an idea how to fix that.

Comment: @fishinear Welp, I know it does look like, like i am a Rookie, and i still am, but i coded many things, which worked well. But Arrays are new and i thought i would get help. I searched quite a lot. BUT nevertheless you could answer my TestMethod question, because i have not the slightes idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could probably be shorter, but it works.

```
public static int findMostCommonElement(int[] list) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i : list)
        if (i > max)
            max = i;
    int[] newArr = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        newArr[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        newArr[list[i]] += 1;
    int mostCommon = 0;
    int mostCommonMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        if (newArr[i] > mostCommonMax) {
            mostCommonMax = newArr[i];
            mostCommon = i;
        }
    return mostCommon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass fixed values to your method, you can use:

```
int[] liste = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
System.out.println(new MostCommonElemnt().findMostCommonElemnt(liste));
```

You can return the second value of the array using `return list[1];` inside the `findMostCommonElemnt` method, but this probably isn't what the method should do.

Comment: Do i just uncomment 
    `int[] liste = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`
in the 
     `public static void main (int[] args)`
?
Because i want, that the Values from `int[] liste = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`
go into my Method `findMostCommonElemnt(int[] list)`

Comment: @StephanL. You also need to remove the `int[]` from the next line and spell list the same each time.

Comment: Because i want, that the Values from `int[] liste = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` go into my Method `findMostCommonElemnt(int[] list)`
I tried it and it works, but not as intended.